# approved organization required for login in a selfhosted Drone.io

Tags: drone.io

I'm self hosting a Drone.io CI.

After a OAuth Apps creation in my Github account and agreed all permissions (also my -public- organisation access), I'm always receiving this error message : [Login Failed. User must be a member of an approved organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFwOn.png)

Can you have an idea about the problem?
Can we disable to have an approved organization and not just get the user repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add the DRONE_USER_FILTER environment variable with my GITHUB username and Drone now show UP.